# JMockIt: Inner class testing

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

So I have a piece of code as follows:

```
 public Observable<Map<String, Object>> fetch(final String id) {
        Client client = mClient.get();

        return client.performRequest(new Client.Request() {
            @Override
            public void doRequest(Subscriber subscriber) {
                Map<String, Object> response = getEndpoint().getUser(id);
                setAttributes(response);
                subscriber.onNext(response);
            }
        });
    }
  /**
     * Get the endpoint
     * @return reference to the endpoint
     */
    private Endpoint getEndpoint() {
        if (mEndpoint == null) {
            RestAdapter restAdapter = getClient().getRestAdapter();
            mEndpoint = restAdapter.create(Endpoint.class);
        }
        return mEndpoint;
    }
```

And here is my test:

```
@Test
public void fetch(@Cascading final Client client,
                  @Mocked final Client.Request request,
                  @Mocked final Subscriber subscriber,
                  @Cascading final User.Endpoint endpoint) {
    new NonStrictExpectations(mUser){{
        mUser.setAttributes((Map) any);
        subscriber.onNext(any);
        Deencapsulation.invoke(mUser, "getEndpoint"); returns(endpoint);
    }};
    // returns the observable
    assertThat(mUser.fetch(User.ID_ME)).isInstanceOf(Observable.class);
    new Verifications() {{
        Client.Request clientRequest;
        client.performRequest(clientRequest = withCapture());
        clientRequest.doRequest(subscriber);
        mUser.setAttributes((Map) any);
        subscriber.onNext(any);
        endpoint.getUser(anyString);
    }};
}
```

For some reason I keep getting an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.magneto.groups.models.User$Endpoint.getEndpoint()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at me.magneto.groups.models.UserTest$1.<init>(UserTest.java:75)
    at me.magneto.groups.models.UserTest.fetch(UserTest.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

I know for a fact I have a private method as listed above getEndpoint which I'm stubbing so a network request isn't made.

So does anyone know what I'm exactly doing wrong? Ideally what I'm trying to test is that a call is made to client (client#performRequest) and that I can test the new Client.Request object by calling on #doRequest and see if it calls the methods inside that. Does anyone have
a suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: `mUser` is instance of which class and `getEndpoint` is method of which class?

Comment: The problem was the order of expectations / verifications, I figured it out on the JMockIt mail list a few days ago... They are all order sensitive since it seems the calls are recorded always in order and not just "if it's called, it's successful"